# Printing PDF or PNG in POS Thermal printer with java

Tags: java, printing, pdfbox, thermal-printer, receipt

I Everyone. I have a problem printing ticket with java. I generated ticket with jasper and then I need to print it in POS Thermal printer. I try to print PDF and the result got 
[Wrong Format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rwng8.jpg)
Then I convert pdf to png with pdfbox but the image print too small. 
How can I print correctly? Is there any way to print PDF for POS Thremal Printer correctly or fill and increase the PNG Image?

[Print PNG too small](https://i.stack.imgur.com/257nj.jpg)

Printing from Adobe reader directly to my POS Thermal Printer, I had the correctly ticket.
[Correct from Adobe Reader](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W7fMz.jpg)

Here's part of my code:

```
PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(new File(pathFile+".pdf"));
            PDPage pd;

            PDFRenderer pdfRenderer = new PDFRenderer(document);

            for (int page = 0; page < document.getNumberOfPages(); ++page)
            {
              pd = document.getPage(page);
              BufferedImage bim = pdfRenderer.renderImageWithDPI(page, 300, ImageType.RGB);
              ImageIOUtil.writeImage(bim, pathFile +".png", 300);

            }
            document.close();

            FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(pathFile+".png");

            DocFlavor flavor = DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.AUTOSENSE;
            DocPrintJob job = mPrinter.createPrintJob();
            Doc doc = new SimpleDoc(is, flavor, null);

            job.print(doc, null);

            is.close();
```

Comment: PDFBox allows to print PDFs directly. To see whether it works at all (there have been many troubles with tiny printers), download the pdfbox-app and try the command line utility https://pdfbox.apache.org/2.0/commandline.html#printpdf . If that works, get the source code and find the file Printing.java that one has several ways to print from PDF.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I could print through PDFBox's print method directly.The difference with adobe reader printing is that I had to fit the page format of my jasper template(receipt template) according to printing width defined in thermal printer technical manual because PDFBox doesn't fit the pdf to paper size.

Comment: There is a PDFBox printing option to fit to size, second parameter of `PDFPrintable` constructor. (Yes, that option isn't available on the command line)